# Excel, VB - Subtract Days from Date Using DateAdd()

Tags: arrays, date, excel, dateadd, vba

## ISSUE

I wish to subtract a 1 to 3 digit number stored in an array from a date field in the worksheet. I take the absolute value of the number, multiply it by negative 1, then use the DateAdd function to perform the operation. I receive no error messages, but the array value remains the exact 1 to 3 digit number originally sent through the process.

## EXAMPLE

Column C is what my current results are giving me.

```
        A        B        C
1  1/8/09       54       54
2  3/3/11        1        1
3  8/1/10      132      132
```

## CODE

```
If delType = "Numeric" Then
    ElseIf delChars = 3 Or delChars = 2 Or delChars = 1 Then
         del(i, 1) = Abs(del(i, 1))
         del(i, 1) = del(i, 1) * -1
         del(i, 1) = DateAdd("d", del(i, 1), Range("E" & i + 1))
         'I did confirm that this case is actually working 
         'by setting the above line to del(i,1) = "Digits" and
         'received "Digits" for all entries with 1 to 3 numeric digits.
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr, x

    arr = Range("A1:A3").Value 'values to be subtracted


    For x = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        ' "base" date is in A5
        arr(x, 1) = Range("A5").Value - Abs(arr(x, 1))
    Next x

    With Range("D1:D3")
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        .Value = arr 'dump values back to sheet
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Excel are stored as number of days since a fixed date. You can just subtract column B from column A directly in the worksheet. No VBA required. Just format the result as a date.

Comment: In other words, Enter `= A2 - B2` in cell `C2`. Format `C2` as a date. Copy down the cell. Done.

Comment: A. Webb, this is just a small part of a much more complex operation. It is vital that this is done inside an array. The 3 digit numbers are  extracted from a string along with many other steps previously while iterating through the array.

Comment: This does not change the fact that you can just parse your numbers and subtract. Taking the absolute value and negating it seems pointless to counterproductive. The title of your question and the code snippet you posted do not seem relevant to the actual problem you are having which is that the result of your code is a copy if the inputs? Please post more code and clarify the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

although your code doesn't show it, my suspicion is that the array is being treated as an **integer**, and you have `On Error Resume Next` in the code.

as the date is too big for an integer, the information is not getting replaced.

try this to see the effect

```
Sub test()
On Error Resume Next
Dim i As Integer
i = Now()
Debug.Print i
End Sub
```

with the error (non)handling in place, you get a result of `0`. Without the error handling, excel stops at the `i=Now()` with an overflow error

Answer (score 1):

Tim's code is actually based on the concept of A.Webb's first comment.

Given, your dates, DAYS are in A, B columns respectively and you could output the answer to column C. You could infact read both column A and B into one 2-D array or two 1-D arrays, used 1 named cell as reference point to all cells you need to interact. That will allow some cell independent/dyanmic process. Again, your issue seems rather tiny - UNLESS your have to deal with Excel Add-Ins from certain vendors who would have some bizzare impact on your data/DATES formats in Excel. I wouldn't recommend having a UDF for you. Since this is a part of a BIG operation flow, you can wrap this under a data manipulation class/module where you do all small yet important data "massaging". Also hope you pay some attention to performance of your sheet when working with DATES in large workbooks.

extremely minor suggestion:

```
arr(x, 1) = Abs(arr(x, 1)) - Range("B1").Offset(x - 1, 0).Value
```